# $wpdb->prepare affecting the query?

Tags: query, wpdb, sql

I need to query all posts using SQL (tried doing it with `WP_Query` didn't work correctly), of certain post types

```
$post_types = get_post_types(); 
unset( $post_types['attachment'], $post_types['nav_menu_item'] );

$post_type_string = '\'' . implode( '\', \'', $post_types ) . '\'';

global $wpdb;
$replace_query = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type IN ( %s )", $post_type_string ), ARRAY_A );
```

The `$post_types` array will give me

```
array( 'post' => 'post', 'page' => 'page', 'revision' => 'revision', 'custom_css' => 'custom_css', 'attachment' => 'attachment', 'nav_menu_item'=> 'nav_menu_item', 'customize_changeset' => 'customize_changeset', 'tt_font_control' => 'tt_font_control' )
```

I imploded this array, to add quotes around the values, and put this in my `$wpdb->prepare` as shown, but all I got was empty array.

When I removed the prepare and did this

```
$replace_query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type IN ( $post_type_string )", ARRAY_A );
```

The query worked and I got back full array.

Why did this happen?

The `$post_type_string` is a string, so `%s` is correct in the prepare.

I tried not 'quoting' the values in the string, but that didn't work as well, and I tried with double quotes. I know that prepare does

```
$query = str_replace( "'%s'", '%s', $query ); // in case someone mistakenly already singlequoted it
$query = str_replace( '"%s"', '%s', $query ); // doublequote unquoting
$query = preg_replace( '|(?<!%)%f|' , '%F', $query ); // Force floats to be locale unaware
$query = preg_replace( '|(?<!%)%s|', "'%s'", $query ); // quote the strings, avoiding escaped strings like %%s
array_walk( $args, array( $this, 'escape_by_ref' ) );
return @vsprintf( $query, $args );
```

}

from [developers prepare docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/). Does this happen because of the quotes? And if so, how to prepare my query correctly?

**EDIT:**

The `WP_Query` that doesn't work as expected

```
$temp_posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => $post_types,
            'posts_per_page' => 1000000,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'post_status' => array( 'any', 'draft' )
            )
        );
```

Comment: When a function, method or code snippet doesn't work as you expect, you sould explain what you expected, what you get and the errors you get, if any; "it doesn't work" says nothing about the problem you may have. Can you explain what exactly "`WP_Query` didn't work correctly" means?

Comment: For some reason it won't fetch all post types, only posts. That's why I used a direct query. Trust me I error logged every single combination before posting this :)

Comment: `WP_Query` works with any post type; if you get only posts of standard post type, then you may be passing wrong data. Can you share your `WP_Query` snippet?

Comment: `$temp_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => $post_types, 'posts_per_page' => 1000000, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'post_status' => array( 'any', 'draft' ) ) );` I didn't use `'posts_per_page' => -1` because that slows the query significantly, and I needed a high number. I tried removing the `no_found_rows`, that did nothing, and I wanted to query everything in the array of post types.

Comment: Please, add the code to the question. Reading large code snipeets in comments is very difficult. Anyway, that `WP_Query` works perfectly here.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's specific to my case, even though it's a simple query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array directly because the [`$wpdb->prepare()` method can be called like `vsprintf()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/#description), which [works like `sprintf()` but accepts arrays of arguments.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php)

```
$post_types = get_post_types(); 
unset( $post_types['attachment'], $post_types['nav_menu_item'] );

global $wpdb;
$replace_query = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type IN ( %s )", $post_types ), ARRAY_A );
```

The problem with your code is that you get a string like this one:

```
"'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'custom_css', 'customize_changeset'"
```

So, the `IN` statement you get is like:

```
IN ( "'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'custom_css', 'customize_changeset'" )
```

Instead of the correct one that would be an array of strings:

```
IN ( 'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'custom_css', 'customize_changeset' )
```

Comment: Really? Because it works as a string without preparing. I didn't try with array tbh

Comment: Answer updated to explain why you can use the array and how to convert it to string if you want.